# Adding data to closing tag of xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm working on an architecture for timing data and I'm considering using `XML` for this purpose. The data is of the format:

```
operation start: name, type
operation end: timing data
```

The data can be nested. `XML` is naturally suited in some ways for this, but while I can store the start data in the start tag, it doesn't look like I can do the same for the closing tag. Or can I?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
Sorry for the delay, hard to type this data with a mobile app... The data will look something like this:

operation:begin: fetch
operation:begin: compute
operation:end: compute timing data
operation:begin: callback
operation:end: callback timing data
operation:end: fetch timing data

Comment: Why not `<operation name="" type=""><timing><starttime val=""/><endtime val=""/></timing></operation>`?

Comment: Or even `<operation name="" type=""><!--Nested Operations --><timing starttime="" endtime=""/></operation>`

Comment: I would keep away from <starttime val=""/> in favour for <starttime>value</starttime>

Comment: There are half a dozen different structures that could be used- we're not sure why you're avoiding them.  Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @LukeAlderton  - I mean, that's an option.  You could (should?) also use name and type as sub tags, instead of attributes.  Kind of depends on what we're doing here.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan I agree.

Comment: Also whoever added the words XML into code blocks needs to stop making pointless edits, it's a name, not code.

Comment: I guess I could just separate the data into individual tags. My worry is that with nested operations, it wouldn't be clear when opened in a browser, say (admittedly not a big concern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use one of the following as a basic structure:

```
<operation name="" type="">
     <!--Nested Operations -->
     <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
</operation>
```

or

```
<operation name="" type="">
     <operations>
         <!--Nested Operations -->
     </operations>
     <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
</operation>
```

I prefer the first, but XML Data structures tend to have plural tags used to denote lists of the same tags.  Depends on your needs/preferences.

Then your nested structure could look like this:

```
<operation name="" type="">
    <operation name="" type="">
    <!--Nested Operations -->
        <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="" type="">
    <!--Nested Operations -->
        <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
    </operation>
    <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
</operation>
```

Or, using the plural tag convention:

```
<operation name="" type="">
    <operations>
        <operation name="" type="">
            <operations>
                <!--Nested Operations -->
            </operations>
            <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="" type="">
            <operations>
                <!--Nested Operations -->
            </operations>
            <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="" type="">
            <operations>
                <!--Nested Operations -->
            </operations>
            <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
        </operation>
    </operations>
    <timing starttime="" endtime=""/>
</operation>
```

Either way, it's simply a manner of, for each operation, using an opening block and an ending block with some information filled in.

Personally, I think either of these is perfectly clear.  Or rather, as clear as XML is ever going to get.  But at the end of the day, your use case (human vs computer reads, transformation, indexing, and reporting needs) will determine your datastructure.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, hard to type this data with a mobile app... The data will look something like this:  


operation:begin: fetch

operation:begin: compute

operation:end: compute timing data

operation:begin: callback

operation:end: callback timing data

operation:end: fetch timing data


So, the suggested formats you recommend could work, though I may just use some unique ID per operation and skip the collections tag... Something to think about I suppose.

Comment: @user1115716 please, when posting XML, or other tag based content, use backticks(`) to denote them and ensure they will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the following:

```
<operation>
    <start>
        <name>value</name>
        <type>value</type>
    </start>
    <end>
        <timingData>value</timingData>
    </end>
</operation>
```